# Enabling KVM without BIOS setup

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, kvm, bios, amd

I'm running Debian 11 LXDE in an old notebook and during the boot I'm receiving the following message:

```
root@debian:~# dmesg | grep -i kvm
[   20.501228] kvm: disabled by bios
[   20.541824] kvm: disabled by bios
```

Also, when I try to create a VM in `virt-manager`, I get the following message:

> Warning: KVM is not available. This may mean the KVM package is not installed, or the KVM kernel modules are not loaded. Your virtual machines may perform poorly.

And indeed the VM performs **very poor**.

However, I'm pretty sure the processor is capable of virtualization:

```
root@debian:~# lscpu | grep -i "virtualization\|svm"
Virtualization:                  AMD-V
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni monitor ssse3 cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch ibs skinit wdt hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter
```

Unfortunately, the BIOS setup is very simple and doesn't have any option of virtualization to be set. Therefore, I can't enable the virtualization via BIOS setup.

##### Question

Is it possible to enable KVM by other means instead of BIOS setup?

---

##### Hardware Specification

- **Product Name:** Acer Aspire E1-421
- **Processor:** AMD E1-1200 Dual-core @ 1.40 GHz
- [Datasheet](https://www.acer.com/datasheets/2013/4876/E1-421/NX.M25AL.004.html)
- [Service Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/483151/Acer-Aspire-E1-421.html)

```
root@debian:~# dmidecode | grep -i "version\|release"
    Version: V2.12
    Release Date: 04/16/2013
    Version: V2.12
    Version: Type2 - A01 Board Version
    Version: Chassis Version
    Version: AMD E1-1200 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
```

Comment: Is your bios up to date?

Comment: @yarl > "Is your bios up to date?" Yes, I'm using the latest one available at the manufacturer website. I've updated the OP with such info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the bios is dumb and the support can't be enabled:
https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/560193/need-help-to-enable-vt-technology-plz-help-aspire-e1-421-11204g32mnks-notebook

Or (I can't recommend that) you have to flash a "modded bios" as they say.

Comment: Any reason why virtualization can only be enabled by BIOS and not via OS?

Comment: Usually: once disabled can't be re-enabled.